# Making composite of two alpha textures in a glsl shader

Tags: opengl-es, libgdx, fragment-shader

I wish to combine two textures in a shader exactly the same as you would expect from a photoshop like program. That is, one texture ontop of another as if layered.
Both textures will have alpha, and *the result output should also have the correct combined alpha.*

So the goal is;
[image: composite image illustration]

However despite googleing for the formula, I am not able to get the correct colors out. 
Using the referance here: (https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/PremultipliedAlpha.htm) for example produces;

[image]

(note difference in grey 50% overlay)

The shader code is set in libgdx to use this as the blending;

```
  context.setBlending(true,GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA ,GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

I am fairly sure the mistake is in my fragment shaders blending (see code in image above), because if I pass the input texture (A) straight to gl_FragColor, then I get a pixel-perfect color match of A, including its alpha.
eg;

gl_FragColor =  backdiffuse;

works fine.

=====

***edit***

Following advice, I have tried using a premulitiplied alpha instead.

```
context.setBlending(true,GL20.GL_ONE, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

However, this produces wrong effects *even when the shader is just set to output A*

```
backdiffuse = texture2D(u_backSample2D, vTexCoord);     
backdiffuse=backdiffuse*backdiffuse.a; //convert to premultiply     
gl_FragColor =  backdiffuse;
```

Am I setting libgdxs blending wrong? This is clearly too bright.

[image]

---

Solution (thanks to accepted answer);

```
 backdiffuse.rgb *= backdiffuse.a; //premultiply source 
 v_backBackColor.rgb *= v_backBackColor.a; //premultiply source 

finalCol.rgb = backdiffuse.rgb + (v_backBackColor.rgb * (1 - backdiffuse.a));       
finalCol.a = backdiffuse.a + (v_backBackColor.a * (1.0 - backdiffuse.a));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the premultiplied alpha equation, you must also draw the output to screen with the appropriate blend equation: GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA.

And the destination alpha must also be multiplied by one minus source alpha. So:

```
finalCol.a = backDiffuse.a + v_backBackColor * (1.0 - backDiffuse.a);
```

If you want to use the more typical blend equation you are currently using, the equations in the shader would be more complicated. You can find them if you look up [alpha compositing on Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing#Alpha_blending). However, premultiplied alpha is a preferred format since it avoids dark or light fringing on antialiased edges of sprites.

Comment: Thanks, it seems premultiplied would make things easier anyway reading around. However, I cant seem to get even a unchanged image to look correct using it (see edited question). I think its now treating the whole image as additive :-/

Comment: `backdiffuse=backdiffuse*backdiffuse.a;` should be `backdiffuse.rgb *= backdiffuse.a;` You're accidentally squaring the alpha, which makes it more glowy in premultiplied alpha blend mode.

Answer (score 0):

Here is function that computes the "over" alpha compositing function (without pre-multiplied alpha).
This is only necessary if both colors are translucent. If you are always blending onto an opaque color, you can use a simpler function.

```
float4 blendOver(float4 a, float4 b) {
    float newAlpha = mix(b.w, 1.0, a.w);
    float3 newColor = mix(b.w * b.xyz, a.xyz, a.w);
    float divideFactor = (newAlpha > 0.001 ? (1.0 / newAlpha) : 1.0);
    return float4(divideFactor * newColor, newAlpha);
}
```